# Creating unique link for blogpost from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So I'm creating a webpage where I call into my database table blog_post. From there I'm accessing the top 10 most recent entries from the table ordered by their post_id. What I'm trying to do is make a unique link to the page /Blogpost.php.  However when I execute this code all that displays is the header 'Recent Posts'. I know it has nothing to do with the connection because other php segments execute appropriately. However, Im struggling to get the links to just appear.

```
<div id="content">
        <div id="sidebarblog">
          <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
          <p id=blglst><?php
              $query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM blog_post ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 10) sub ORDER BY post_id DESC";
              $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
                $title = $row['title'];
                $id=$row['post_id'];
                echo ("<a href='http://domain/Blogpost.php?id=" . $id . "'>" . $title . "</a><br />");
              }
            ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you are mixing mysql and mysqli. I don't think that this is a good thing. try a `var_dump(expressions and vars here)` to see the result of your php execution

Comment: "Not a good thing" is a polite way of saying "it won't work". Use `mysqli_` functions, the `mysql_` functions are deprecated in php 5 and **removed** in php 7.

Comment: see [https://stackoverflow.com/a/31319761/6838730](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31319761/6838730)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing appears it most likely means that you do not enter the `while` part of your code.

You can try running the query directly against the database (using PhpMyAdmin for example) or you can try using `var_dump()` to debug your code and see if `$result` and `$row` contain data.

update : After looking it up, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31319761/6838730) and [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), mixing APIs isn't a very good idea ...

Comment: Oh my gosh I forgot the 'i'.... Fixed the issue! Thanks!